# Dynamically generate tasks, using `ds` in Airflow

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have multiple tables in a database, and based on whether a corresponding column is more recent than `ds` should it be added to the DAG as a task.

```
                            1
                            2
validate_sources ->  __multiple_sources__  -> aggregations -> validate
                            3
                            4
                            N
```

That is, I want the sources to run in parallel (each a single task), which is no problem, and if I wanted a single source only after `ds` then that would work, but the combination of `ds` and dynamic generation I do not know how to do, as `ds` is not available at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier to always have the `aggregations` and `validate` tasks for each source but if they haven't been updated just short circuit the downstream tasks so they don't run.